# Make Atom or VSCode recognise Git Repo created using WSL

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Now that Windows 10 Creators update improved WSL (Windows Sub-system for Linux AKA Bash for Windows), there's still small limitation bothering me.

If I create a Git repo from inside Bash, and open that repo in Atom Editor or VS Code, it doesn't recognise the directory as a valid Git repo, this is obvious since underlying `node-git` thinks it is on Windows, so only Git repos created using "Windows Git" is valid Git repo. Is there any way I make these editors treat Git repos from WSL as valid Git repo?

Answer (score 0):

You should not experience any problems, provided that:

1. You have Git installed on both WSL and Windows (Atom and VS Code integrate with the Git installed on Windows).
2. You did not create any repositories within the WSL `/root` or `/home` directories (those are not visible on Windows due to interoperability issues with the WSL filesystem).

For more information on the topic of interoperability issues with the WSL filesystem:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, with WSL2, the answer appears to be to ensure that you have to have the default user set in `/etc/wsl.conf`.

i.e. **/etc/wsl.conf:**

```
[user]
default=<username>
```

Clue is in in [this github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4508) about file saves. A commenter states

> Right now, by-design, WSL interop leans heavily on the "default user" paradigm.

Therefore, solution is (in my case at least)

1. Update WSL config, as above
2. Restart your WSL and VSCode. A reboot may be needed.